# What should I take into consideration when setting worker_connections settings for gunicorn used with gevent?

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

I want to tune my gevent workers in a rest application, and I see that you can change the default worker_connections from the default of 1000. I can't find any information on how to think about what number of connections is appropriate though. What should this setting depend on?